# Pandas Timeseries: Total duration meeting a specific condition

Tags: pandas

I have a timeseries

```
ts = pd.Series(data=[0,1,2,3,4],index=[pd.Timestamp('1991-01-01'),pd.Timestamp('1995-01-01'),pd.Timestamp('1996-01-01'),pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01'),pd.Timestamp('2011-01-01')])
```

Whats the fastest, most readable, way to get the total duration in which the value is below 2, assuming the values are valid until the next time-step indicates otherwise (no linear interpolation). I imagine there probably is a pandas function for this

Comment: Is there a reason this was voted down?

Comment: for future reference I'd love an explaination into what went wrong here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working quite well, however I am still baffled that there does not seem to be a pandas function for this!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ts = pd.Series(data=[0,1,2,3,4],index=[pd.Timestamp('1991-01-01'),pd.Timestamp('1995-01-01'),pd.Timestamp('1996-01-01'),pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01'),pd.Timestamp('2011-01-01')])

# making the timeseries binary. 1 = meets condition, 0 = does not
ts = ts.where(ts>=2,other=1)
ts = ts.where(ts<2,other=0)

delta_time = ts.index.to_pydatetime()[1:]-ts.index.to_pydatetime()[:-1]

time_below_2 = np.sum(delta_time[np.invert(ts.values[:-1])]).total_seconds()
time_above_2 = np.sum(delta_time[(ts.values[:-1])]).total_seconds()
```

The above function seems to break for certain timeframes. This option is slower, but did not break in any of my tests:

```
def get_total_duration_above_and_below_value(value,ts):

    # making the timeseries binary. 1 = above value, 0 = below value
    ts = ts.where(ts >= value, other=1)
    ts = ts.where(ts < value, other=0)

    time_above_value = 0
    time_below_value = 0
    for i in range(ts.size - 1):
        if ts[i] == 1:
            time_above_value += abs(pd.Timedelta(
                ts.index[i] - ts.index[i + 1]).total_seconds()) / 3600
        else:
            time_below_value += abs(pd.Timedelta(
                ts.index[i] - ts.index[i + 1]).total_seconds()) / 3600

    return time_above_value, time_below_value
```